# Why Android NDK's System.loadLibrary tries to load a SONAME

Tags: android, linker, android-ndk, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have a vendor library that I need to link against: `libSnpeHta.so`

I successfully can link against it in the `Android.mk`

```
...
# main project
LOCAL_MODULE := mylib
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += snpe_hta
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
...
# dependency
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := snpe_hta
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(SNPE_LIB_DIR)/libSnpeHta.so
#$(shell cp $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES) $(TARGET_OUT))
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Then when I run inside my main Java activity:

```
static {
      System.loadLibrary("mylib");
}
```

It tries to load this particular library by a SONAME and fails:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libQnnHta.so" not found
> at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1071)
> at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1007)
> at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1667)
> at com.saicm.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:49)

When I call `./aarch64-linux-android-readelf.exe -d <project_path>/lib/aarch64-android-clang8.0/libSnpeHta.so` to check the dependencies of this library I get

```
Dynamic section at offset 0x134498 contains 28 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [liblog.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdl.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so]
 0x000000000000000e (SONAME)             Library soname: [libQnnHta.so]
```

I have no idea how the vendor distributes `libQnnHta.so`, I don't have this file, and I'm really puzzled why I need the SONAME library when I have `libSnpeHta.so` already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rename `libSnpeHta.so` to `libQnnHta.so`. I have no idea why the vendor named the library wrong, but the `SONAME` field is meant to be the name of the library.

If that doesn't fix it, check that the library is actually being copied to your APK.

Comment: Well I tried to copy into the APK two duplicates of the library with these 2 different names. So far it works (atleast no crashes). Hard to say if it could fail on some other hardware